# Python - Regex, look behind

Tags: python, regex

I want to add a newline after "CREATE TABLE tablename (", so my idea was to match the first occurence of `(` and replace it by `(\n`:

Source Text:

```
abcd
something
CREATE TABLE schema.test1(attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;

efgh
something else
CREATE TABLE schema.test2(columna DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
columnb DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
columnc DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;
```

Desired Result:

```
abcd
something
CREATE TABLE schema.test1(
attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;

efgh
something else
CREATE TABLE schema.test2(
columna DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
columnb DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
columnc DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;
```

I managed to match the text before including the bracket:

```
(?=CREATE\ TABLE).+?\(
```

How can I match **only** the first bracket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a **Lookbehind** here.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)(CREATE *TABLE[^(]*\()', "\\1\n", data)
```

**Note**: The inline `(?i)` modifier is placed here for case insensitive matching.

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/155155)</kbd>

Comment: What stands (?i) for?

Comment: [`(?i)` is a modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make it case-insensitive. You should probably use this on my example as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that `(?=...)` is a **lookahead**, `(?<=...)` is a **lookbehind**.  Since we not only need to match `CREATE TABLE`, but also the table name..this is a 'variable' length, and can't be put in a lookbehinds (only lookaheads can be variable length).  We can still put the `CREATE TABLE` in a lookbehind, but that kind of defeats the purpose since we would still need to use a capture/reference for the table name.

Because of this, I simply matched `CREATE TABLE` followed by 1+ non-`(` characters, finally followed by our `(`.  During our replacement, we can reference all of this matched data using `\0` and append it with a `\n`.

```
CREATE\s+TABLE\s+[^(]+\(
\0\n
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aP7hZ9)

---

**Output:**

```
abcd
something
CREATE TABLE schema.test1(
attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;    

efgh
something else
CREATE TABLE schema.test2(
columna DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
columnb DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
columnc DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;
```

---

**Note:** I replaced  with `\s+`, which allows for 1+ characters of whitespace.

Comment: your demo is matching the table name, everything after CREATE TABLE until inclusively (. I need something else, as I explained above...

Comment: I know how mine works, it also gives you the exact "desired result" as you asked.  Did you check the demo..?

Comment: Ok, so you match everything, and replace the matched string with itself plus a newline. That works, thank you.

Comment: Yup, `\0` references the entire match and then we append the `\n`.  Please accept if it helped :)